# SQL Server from X columns make 1 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I have example table like this:

```
Column1    Column2     Column3        Column4          Column5
---------------------------------------------------------------
Dog         456         Long           Short            Small
Car         454         Blue           NULL             NULL
Fruit       466         Apple          Pear             NULL
```

And I expect table like this when XY columns will be put into 1 column

```
Column1    Column2     Column3
------------------------------
Dog         456         Long
Dog         456         Short
Dog         456         Small
Car         454         Blue
Fruit       466         Apple
Fruit       466         Pear
```

Thank you for your opinions when tables have over thousand rows.

Even I can do this in excel and then back import data to SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unpivot as below:

```
Select * from #unpivotdata
unpivot( cols for col in([column3],[column4],[column5])) u
```

Output as below:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Column1 | column2 | cols  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Dog     |     456 | Long  |
| Dog     |     456 | Short |
| Dog     |     456 | Small |
| Car     |     454 | Blue  |
| Fruit   |     466 | Apple |
| Fruit   |     466 | Pear  |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM table WHERE Column3 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column4 FROM table WHERE Column4 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column5 FROM table WHERE Column5 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col4
FROM tab
WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
SELECT col1, col2, col5
FROM tab
WHERE col5 IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

UnPivot would be more performant, but if the number of columns is unknowm.

You many notice that only the "**Key**" columns are identified, so the width is dynamic.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Column1] varchar(50),[Column2] varchar(50),[Column3] varchar(50),[Column4] varchar(50),[Column5] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Dog',456,'Long','Short','Small')
,('Car',454,'Blue',NULL,NULL)
,('Fruit',466,'Apple','Pear',NULL)

Select A.[Column1]
      ,A.[Column2]
      ,[Column3] = C.Value
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Column1','Column2')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]